# THG strip does not keep changes in the working directory

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I committed a changeset which is now in the "draft" Phase. It is the latest (local) revision. I want to remove that changeset and move all the changes back to the working directory. That means I want the opposite of committing it (which is working directory -> revision).

I tried the `strip` command with both `keep` and without. In both cases my changeset is removed but the changes are gone and the working directory is still empty. Then I need to `unbundle` the backup and `pull` it, at which point I'm exactly where I started with the local changeset in the history.

How do I move the changes from the committed changeset to the working directory? Maybe `backout`?

I'm using TortoiseHg but can also use the console there.

Comment: From the command line, `hg strip -r <rev> --keep` does what you want. Perhaps the TortoiseHG GUI just does it wrong.

Comment: When you say "patch" I think you just mean commit (or revision)? Not an actual Mercurial patch?

Comment: @DaveInCaz Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I managed to solve it, though I don't really understand how it works.

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14155915/3520484) I updated to my revision, switch to Ammend which showed the patch changes in the *working directory as well as the revision*, then `strip` with `keep` removed the revision, only the working directory now contains the files because of Ammend.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer the issue about the behavior of strip, but another way to do this in THG would be:

1. Shelve anything of value in your working folder
2. Update to the last-desired revision (the one before the revision you mean to undo)
3. Select the revision you want to undo and click "Revert All Files..."
4. Let it revert. The working folder will now match the revision you want to undo.
5. Strip (without "keep") the unwanted revision. Or even just leave it there and ignore it.