# How do I edit an incorrect commit message in TortoiseHG Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I mistakenly did a **TortoiseHG** commit while trying to do a new line, and wrote the totally wrong thing in the commit message. How can I change the commit message here ?

I have not yet pushed the commit.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Select "Amend current revision" from dropdown menu of commit button (marked on screenshot). Button title will become "Amend". Enter new commit message and click amend button.

[image: TortoiseHG]

Comment: Note that you can't do this if the revision has already been pushed. So this makes the `--pushafter=` option (automatically push after a commit) less attractive.

Answer (score 7):

- Histedit extension allow you to edit commit message
- You can perform next commit (change nothing) with `--amend` option and corrected commit message

> hg add
>   adding file.txt
>
> hg commit -m "Init"
>
> hg commit -m "Initial commit" --amend
>   saved backup bundle to 719f9ea026f3-amend-backup.hg
>
> hg log

```
changeset:   0:355197b0c857
...
summary:     Initial commit
```